# How to scrape data from a website after a java script is executed in C# asp.net web forms

Tags: c#, web-scraping, webforms

What I have tried is using HtmlAgilityPack but this does not return the full page.

```
var getHtmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();
var document = getHtmlWeb.Load(uri);
var aTags = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul[@class='category-sub-list list-unstyled show-el']");
```

please help

Comment: The webpage has scripts running and you need to wait for scripts to complete before reading results.

Comment: yes please help

Comment: Is this the entirety of your source code @user14354602? What output are you getting? Have you tried the suggestion by @jdweng?

Comment: i have no idea  how to do that @jdweng  plz help

Comment: https://html-agility-pack.net/from-browser ... _"Load Html From Browser - 
HtmlWeb.Load method gets an HTML document from a web browser. It makes it possible to wait for JavaScript to be run by customizing the isBrowserScriptCompleted parameter."_

Comment: https://html-agility-pack.net/from-browser this is for windows form and i am working with web form'

Comment: If you can't instantiate a WebBrowser control then you're out of luck. But try it, just in case it will actually work outside a Forms application. After that your other option would be to try and use another headless browser tool - there are a few around. The point is, you need some sort of environment which can execute JavaScript before you try to parse the HTML. Either that or see if the site you are calling to has an API which is designed to return machine-readable data instead of trying to parse HTML.